# Event listener not thrown because of registering issue

Tags: symfony, dispatcher

I have a problem trying to register my own Event/Listener to the event dispatcher. What I'm registering through the services of my bundle @MyBundle/Resources/services.yml is loaded only during the rendering process, so it's not available when doing a dispatch in the controler.

```
    webservice.listener.data_connect:
    class: Trav\CoreBundle\EventListener\WebService\WebServiceListener
    arguments:
        mailer: '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: trav.webservice.error_connection, method: onDataConnectEvent, class: Trav\CoreBundle\EventListener\WebService\WebServiceListener }
```

but when doing that in the defaultControler:

```
$this->event_dispatcher = $this->container->get("event_dispatcher");
    $this->event_dispatcher->dispatch("travelyo.webservice.listener.data_connect", new DataConnectEvent(array()));
```

It's not working, trying to debug, I can see that in the dispatch method, it cannot find the listener I want to attach.

When trying to put in the event kernel.request instead of trav.webservice.error_connection so it's working(listener is not called, see in the debug bar), but the Event i ge in the WebServiceListener::OnDataConnect is GetResponseEvent and not DataConnectEvent.

Is someone has any idea whats wrong here ?
I've been inspired from this: http://iamproblematic.com/leveraging-the-symfony2-event-dispatcher/.

Which seems to work exactly the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event you dispatch needs to match the event you are listening for.  The example code is sending a **travelyo.webservice.listener.data_connect** event and the listener is configured to receive the **trav.webservice.error_connection** event, which means that this listener will not receive the event.